# Continue 2 levels deep in JS

Tags: javascript, loops, continue

Consider this very simple code:

```
someLabel:
for (var i=0; i<newFonts.length; i++) {
    var newFont = newFonts[i];

    for (var j=0; j<oldFonts.length; j++) {
        var oldFont = oldFonts[j];

        if (fb.equals(oldFont, newFont)) {
            // Break out of inner loop, don't finish outer iteration, continue with next outer item
            continue 2;
        }
    }

    // This must only happen if `newFont` doesn't match ANY `oldFonts`
    oldFonts.push(newFont);
}
```

What it's **supposed** to do is compare all `oldFonts` **objects** with `newFonts` **objects** and only add `newFont` to `oldFonts` (`oldFonts.push`) if it doesn't already exist (`fb.equals`).

`oldFonts` and `newFonts` are objects with `name` and `host` properties. Both are used in `fb.equals()` to determine equality. `indexOf()` won't work.

This is exactly how I'd do it in PHP. It doesn't work in JS, because JS doesn't support `continue 2`, which means continue 2 levels.

How do I do this in JS??

- `continue` wont do, because it'll still finish the inner loop and end up at the `push`
- `break` won't do, because it'll skip the inner loop and jump straight to the `push`
- `break someLabel` won't do, because I don't want to skip ALL `newFonts` when ONE must be ignored

This must be possible without a single function...

Comment: `continue someLabel`?

Comment: @dfsq Is that a question or an answer?

Comment: You are redefining `var i` in the inner loop. Use a different variable.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue#Using_continue_with_a_label

Comment: @GOTO0 Very good point. Updated question.

Comment: I would avoid just for looping and using labels (?).  The solution below with filter is much more smart javascript

Comment: @harmonickey Which solution below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments demonstrated how to continue to a labeled statement.  But as to your original problem, you might be able to solve it more easily:

```
var difference = function(x, y) {
    return x.filter(function(e) {return y.indexOf(e) < 0;});
};

// or oldFonts = ... if you prefer to mutate
var combinedFonts = oldFonts.concat(difference(newFonts, oldFonts));
```

**Update**

If the requirement for testing equality is more sophisticated, as noted in the comments, then something slightly more is needed.  To my mind, this is still simpler than the original approach with labeled loops:

```
var complement = function(pred, a, b) {
    return a.filter(function(x) {
        return !b.some(function(y) {return pred(x, y);});
    });
};

var sameName = function(a, b) {return a.name === b.name;};

var combinedFonts = oldFonts.concat(complement(sameName, newFonts, oldFonts));
```

You can see this **[on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/6pzojhs1/)**

---

I can't wait for fat-arrows to be widely available.  Here's the equivalent:

```
var complement = (pred, a, b) => a.filter(x => !b.some(y => pred(x, y)));
var sameName = (a, b) => a.name === b.name;
```

Comment: `oldFonts` and `newFonts` aren't `Array<String>`, they're `Array<Font>` with `Font.name` being the font, so `indexOf()` won't work. I see now that's wasn't obvious, at all. Updated question.

Comment: Updated the answer to deal with a more sophisticated matching mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like this would help solve your problem:

```
var oldfonts = ['courier new', 'comic sans', 'century gothic'];
var newfonts = ['times new roman', 'comic sans', 'wingdings'];
var addfonts = [];
for (var i = 0; i < newfonts.length; i++) {
    if (oldfonts.indexOf(newfonts[i]) < 0) { // if newfonts item doesnt exist in oldfonts array
        addfonts.push(newfonts[i]); // add it to addfonts array to be added to oldfonts array systematically after all different font items are found           
    }
}
for(var i = 0; i < addfonts.length; i++) {
    oldfonts.push(addfonts[i]); // push add fonts to oldfonts array
    console.log(oldfonts);
}
```

Comment: `oldFonts` and `newFonts` aren't `Array<String>`, they're `Array<Font>` with `Font.name` being the font, so `indexOf()` won't work. I see now that's wasn't obvious, at all. Updated question.